# Can I list only specific subdirectories?

Tags: shell-script, files, ls

I have a folder tree structure like

```
arndell
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
claremont
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
monte
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
```

and I am only after all files inside weekly and daily directories. Is there a way I can achieve that using shell command or commands?

I tried `ls -R */weekly/` from the top folder but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, from the top (the parent of the `arndell`, `claremont`, and `monte`) directories you could type:

```
ls */*/{weekly,daily}
```

Which expands to:

```
ls */*/weekly */*/daily
```

Which would show you the contents of all the `weekly` and `daily` directories.

Comment: I need to use a string to refine the search and actually do one `ls` for weekly and another for daily so `ls */*/weekly/*NODE*` is the winner. Thank you

Comment: Out of my curiosity.... is there any way how to do ls without knowing the tree structure? Only knowing that let's say I want to list all `weekly` directories?

Comment: You could `find . -name weekly | xargs ls`

Comment: It works but it's much much very much slower. It took 30mins compare to a sec using ls.

Comment: The `find` command walks the directory tree.  There are a number of things you could do to speed it up, including restricting the search to directories, limiting the maximum depth of the search, etc.

Comment: @Radek see my answer using `find`.

Comment: In follow-up to [Radek's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7221) [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35584/can-i-list-only-specific-subdirectories#comment48230_35585), what about using a tool (preferably `ls`) to print subdirectories `n` levels deep from a certain subdirectory, without knowing the names of said subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

if you have bash you could use:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in  **/{daily,weekly}/*; do
  whatever $f
done
```

Comment: I need to use one command as I am going to call it from php. I like that in your solution I don't need to know the tree structure. It will list weekly and daily. I haven't try it though.

Comment: as one command just to : `bash -c 'shopt -s globstar; ls -1 **/{daily,weekly}/*'`

Answer (score 2):

```
find . '(' -path '*/weekly/*' -o -path '*/daily/*' ')' -type f
```

Comment: I have to compare the processing speed of `ls` and `find`.

Comment: The answers using `ls` aren't really using `ls`.  They're using shell expansion, so it depends on the speed of your shell.

Comment: `ls */*/weekly` isn't using ls?

Comment: `ls` is doing the printing, but the shell is doing the finding.

Comment: Quick time execution comparison of `ls (5sec)` and `find (14 mins)`... does that mean that shell is faster than find?

Comment: What directory are you running this from?  How long does a simple `find .` take?

Comment: I run the command in the root of the directories as in my example above. `/var/lib/edumate/bdrs` Plain `find .` takes 15m to execute.